# xcode - Need suggestion comment in source file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I started adding comments to the code while i am developing the app (objective-c). The bad thing which i am noticing is the breakpoints and warning or error reporting, it is actually showing a wrong line number or pointing to incorrect line number, is there a solution for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you rebuilding after adding the comments and it's showing the wrong line number?

Comment: Yes -- rebuilding should do the trick.

Comment: yes i build it after typing the comments, i guess @patrick goley is right, could be something to do with derived data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a problem with your Derived Data, the build products that are cached after each build so they don't have to be rebuilt if they aren't changed. The problem is, sometimes Xcode doesn't recognize a change, and what you see in the editor no longer matches the build product. Clean your product with Shift Command K to do a full rebuild. This should fix the inconsistencies you're seeing.

Comment: i deleted the derived data and everything started working fine. thanks pat !